# Python / Pandas - Selecting outliers based in column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
                 code    year             unit
0       3374312000153    2010              reg 
1       3374312000153    2009              reg
2      48300560000198    2014                k
3      48300560000198    2013                k
4      48300560000198    2012                k
5      48300560000198    2011                k
6      48300560000198    2015              reg
7      48300560000198    2016                k
8       7350260000136    2013                k
9       7350260000136    2012                k
...
```

I want to:

a) Check if for one same code, all values in the column "unit" are the same

b) If there is one "unit" that is different, point out which is the different year. This might only be applicable when the same code appears in more than 2 lines (if it is in a single line or in two lines we can't track "the different one")

So, as output for this df in the example we should get this:

```
df_outliers:

                 code    year             unit
6      48300560000198    2015              reg
...
```

Can someone help on that?

Comment: for b) can you explain further on what you mean "different year"? how would that logic play out? which is the latest year? most common year?

Comment: @MattR every year someone goes physically where "code" is and check what is the "unit" for that "code". it happens once a year. I need to track in the past if in any year that "unit" of the "code" was different from its mode, and I need to know on which year it happened. did it get clearer?

Comment: slightly! how would one know if a value is different from its mode? how is mode defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're alright with the result as a list of tuples, then here's a solution involving `groupby`.

```
g = df.groupby('code')

i = g.unit.size()
j = g.unit.nunique()   
k = g.unit.value_counts(sort=False)

k.loc[k.index.levels[0][i.gt(2) & j.ge(2)]].groupby(level=0).idxmin().tolist()
[(48300560000198, 'reg')]
```

---

**Details**

`i` will find the size of each group -

```
i

code
3374312000153     2
7350260000136     2
48300560000198    6
Name: unit, dtype: int64
```

`j` will find the number of unique items per group -

```
j 

code
3374312000153     1
7350260000136     1
48300560000198    2
Name: unit, dtype: int64
```

`k` stores value counts per `code` and `unit` -

```
k

code            unit
3374312000153   reg     2
7350260000136   k       2
48300560000198  k       5
                reg     1
Name: unit, dtype: int64
```

`i.gt(2) & j.ge(2)` indexes on the condition you're looking for -

```
code
3374312000153     False
7350260000136     False
48300560000198     True
Name: unit, dtype: bool
```

This mask is used to index into `k`, to get only the IDs we're interested in. From that point on, apply another `groupby` and `idxmin` to get outliers.

Comment: `i.gt(2) & j.ge(2)` nice one :-) ,like the way your name the parameter :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of nunique and count (strangly size didn't work here) with transform to filter the dataframe

```
df['unit_nunqiue'] = df.groupby('code')['unit'].transform('nunique')
df['unit_count'] = df.groupby(['code','unit'])['year'].transform('count')
df.loc[(df['unit_nunqiue']>1)&(df['unit_count']==1)].drop(['unit_nunqiue','unit_count'], axis=1)
             code  year unit
6  48300560000198  2015  reg
```

Answer (score 0):

We using `value_counts` here

```
df1=df.groupby('code').unit.apply(pd.value_counts)
df1.loc[((df1.sum(level=0)>2)&(df1.groupby(level=0).count()>=2)).idxmax(),:].idxmin()
Out[43]: (48300560000198, 'reg')
```